# Gitlab runner run my ci deploy in master branch with shared runner

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have remote server ubuntu 16 in digitalocean. Also I install gitlab-runner and configure them and add gitlab-ci-yml file in my project.
Sometimes(1/99) it run correctly, but mostly it doesn't run.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

  [session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Gitlab-Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "***"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

My gitlab-ci-yml

```
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - deploy
test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo run tests in this section

step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
    - pip install docker-compose
    - sudo docker image prune -f
    - sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
    - sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Also this running in "gitlab-runner 11.5.0". But my server use "gitlab-runner 11.6". I have this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.0 (3afdaba6)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Using Docker executor with image docker ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image 
sha256:dfd9350d475b431e4b9b037fe31f4f0df70d597688776f3b10 
for docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image docker ...
Using docker image 
sha256:21df41782cc5884b85b5d32f3d0ec552aaee788ac0a7a36d7d4e4b0 for 
docker ...
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-10114523-concurrent-0 via runner- 
fa6cab46-srm-1546518230-c1805b24...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/marattm/investordatabase'...
Checking out b15507d3 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
/bin/sh: eval: line 68: sudo: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

In this case, gitlab ci not using my runner,that i config. It using shared runner
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.0 (3afdaba6)
>    on docker-auto-scale

Gitlab runner on docker-auto-scale are the public shared runner provided by gitlab.com
Go to settings -> ci/cd -> runner -> right site are all shared runner listed with it tags.

There are two methods to avoid using shared runner.

a) Go to settings -> ci/cd -> runner -> click "disable shared runners"
b) give your runner a unique tag and use this tag on all your jobs. this will ensure that the job is only executed on the runner which has this tag.

For more information:
  * https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags
  * https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags

Comment: If i disable shared runners, when i running, getting error 'This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it.' But in config CI/CD i have runner with active status